# c# mvc array in script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Please help how can i bind my ArrayList into javascript from viewbag

```
 static List<MapC> cor=new List<MapC>() {new MapC() {Xcor = -25.363 ,Ycor = 131.044}}; 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ListT = cor; 
        return View(new MapC() {Xcor = 150.644 });
    }
```

this my html

```html
 <script>
        var map;

        function initMap() {
            var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatLng
            });
           //this i want loop my list from viewbag
 </script>
```

Comment: what is the problem your facing???

Comment: if i use @foreach i can not use my script in foreach

Comment: if i understood correctly you want to loop throught the `viewbag.ListT` ?

Comment: yes. and use scriptin my loop

Answer (score 1):

**MVC Action:**

// Before assigning convert it to Json

```
ViewBag.ListT = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cor);
return View(new MapC() {Xcor = 150.644 });
```

**JS:**

Just make sure that jQuery is loaded before you run that script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       // Your Code....
        .......
        var Listval= '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ListT)';
        //Loop through ListT

    data = $.parseJSON(Listval);
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    alert(item.Xcor);
    alert(item.Ycor);
});
```

Comment: `var x= value.Xcor' and `var y= value.Ycore` will do

Comment: Try this: `for(var i=0;i<Listval.length;i++){ console.log(Listval[i].Xcor)}`

Comment: sry i missed the ' ' marks in @Html.Raw..  it should be  `'@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ListT)';`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '60' in [{"Xcor":52.511,"Ycor":13.447},{"Xcor":52.549,"Ycor":13.422}]

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your `ViewBag` property to a javascript object, for example

```
var list = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ListT))');
```

and then you can access then in a loop, for example to get the first `Xcor` value

```
var xcor = list[0].Xcor;
```